# Out of memory opencv haartraining

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

I have 30 positive images and 60 negatives images.
When I tried to execute the haartraining with 4GB of memory and Quadcore processor machine, I get this error message:

```
   OpenCV ERROR: Insufficient memory (Out of memory)
      in function cvAlloc, cxalloc.cpp(111)
   Terminating the application...
      called from cvUnregisterType, cxpersistence.cpp(4933)
```

The command is:

```
./opencv-haartraining -vec vector/myvector.vec -bg negatives.txt -npos 24 -nneg 55 -mem 2048 -mode ALL -w 86 -h 150
```

The computer has only 765 MB used, but the process exceeds the given limit, and uses a lot of memory in swap until the overflow occurs. Any suggestions of what can be done to solve this problem?

Regards

Comment: What is the "myvector.vec" size?

Comment: `-w 86 -h 150`  that is very large. try a smaller window.

Comment: Do you have a 32bit OS?

Comment: @VAndrei The OS is 64bit

Comment: Thank you @berak, really, the size of images is very large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your "myvector.vec" is too big. All these pictures are loaded to RAM.
Try to resize the images.

Comment: Thank you, the number of images and the size were allocating memory from my computer.

Comment: I was testing with only 66 pos (55x55 pixel) and 150 negative samples (about 150x150). The positive samples .vec file is only 400kb sized, why do I still get "out of memory" errors? If I reduce to 20x20 I can proceed, but 55x55 would be better for my specialuzed application, I guess. Any idea why this error occurs? It looks like a single malloc wants to allocate about 1GB of memory,  Is this the memory needed to save all temporary haar data/results or something?